# how to fill a QGraphicsRectItem with certain color?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsrectitem

I have been trying to find a way to fill an instance of QGraphicsRectItem with any color, let's say red color, but I failed to find a clear way as of how to accomplish this naive task, It would be great if you could provide some hints, links, etc.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`setBrush()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractgraphicsshapeitem.html#setBrush):

```
your_rect_item->setBrush(Qt::red)
```